# SideNav link does not appear inside navbar

Tags: html, css, webpack, materialize, symfony4

I want to create an Admin menu. Inside my Navbar I want to add a icon and when you press the icon the sidenav appear. But the fact is when I copy paste the code from [the Materialize doc](https://materializecss.com/sidenav.html) It works, when I insert

```
<a href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
```

When i put this line inside `nav` the Menu Icon and text does not appear, and I don't know why...
Outside the Nav tag :

[image]

The sidenav could appear :

[image]

But I put the link inside my navbar :

[image]

Here is my code :

HTML :

```
<nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>

            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">

                <li><a href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger">menu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav">
        <li><div class="user-view">
                <div class="background">
                    <img src="#">
                </div>
                <a href="#user"><img class="circle" src="#"></a>
                <a href="#name"><span class="white-text name">John Doe</span></a>
                <a href="#email"><span class="white-text email">jdandturk@gmail.com</span></a>
            </div></li>
        <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>First Link With Icon</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">Second Link</a></li>
        <li><div class="divider"></div></li>
        <li><a class="subheader">Subheader</a></li>
        <li><a class="waves-effect" href="#!">Third Link With Waves</a></li>
    </ul>
```

And inside my `app.js` :

```
    M.AutoInit();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal').modal();
    $('.sidenav').sidenav({
            menuWidth: 300, // Default is 240
            edge: 'left', // Choose the horizontal origin
            closeOnClick: true // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
        }
    );
});
```

I'm running out of ideas, I don't why this does not appear..

Comment: where is your css?

Comment: I had nothing inside, I'm using webpack encore on the Symfony 4 Project.The only line I have on the CSS is : ```@import "~materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss"; ```

Comment: I can't see the rendered results is the ul actually being rendered outside the nav?

Comment: the render of the sidenav is correct. I just can't put the link insode my navbar it does not appear

Comment: I think the problem id from Webpack, I can't even change the Text color inside my navbar or can't applied a background color inside my CSS.

Comment: Webpack doesn't modify CSS or HTML, it just "pack" (can minimize too) it to have less files. I don't thin the problem is there. Can you try to make a jsFiddle to reproduce the problem ?

Comment: Here it is all my code is here : https://jsfiddle.net/2damuzk1/